# Dynamically routing hosts to docker

Tags: nginx, docker, routes

I'm trying to dynamically route web hosts to LAMP docker containers. 
Kinda how "apache dynamic virtual hosts" routes web hosts to their webroot folder based on their name (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/mass.html).

I'm trying route web hosts to docker with the same host name using an nginx docker on the same VM.

Comment: use a dockerized reverse proxy to do the routing in front of everything else

Comment: But how can it route dynamically to the appropriate docker container?

Comment: your reverse proxy would do that part.  you could use nginx if you're familiar with that. lots of folk use it that way.  it would know how because you tell it how.

Answer (score 1):

here is a good solution:
https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy
its not dynamic but it can be configured with a shell script